# For loop list of datetimes with month as condition

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, for-loop, if-statement, error-handling

```
y=[datetime.datetime,2016,4,27), datetime.datetime,2016,4,26)]
date1=[datetime.datetime,2016,4,28), datetime.datetime,2016,4,27)]

for item in y:
data2=[]
        for item in data1:
            if item.month==y.month and item.day==y.day:
                 data2.append(item.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))
```

This gives the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'month'. 
So how can I loop through a list of datetimes using the month as a condition? I'm using Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your python code is incomplete (brackets missing)...

one of the problems is that both your loop variables have the same name: `item`.

the mentioned error comes from the fact that `y` is a list and you are asking for `y.month`.

i renamed `y` to `date0` and labelled the 2 necessary loop vars with `item0` and `item1`. this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

date0 = [datetime(2016, 4, 27), datetime(2016, 4, 26)]
date1 = [datetime(2016, 4, 28), datetime(2016, 4, 27)]

ret = []
for item0 in date0:
    for item1 in date1:
        if item0.month == item1.month and item0.day == item1.day:
            ret.append(item0.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))
print(ret)
```

(if you also want the year to be equal you could just do `if item0 == item1:`).